# Removing Orphan Entries from an MS Project Resource Pool?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

We are using Project 2013 (Standard) and have defined a 'Resource Pool.mpp' to share resources across multiple project (.mpp) files.

Older project files that were linked have been moved, removed or renamed on the file system causing the shared resource links within the Resource Pool file to be broken. This has resulted in orphan task entries and overallocation of resources.

I am unable to remove the broken links via opening the Resource Pool in read/write mode and clicking the 'Break Link' button.

Is there any other way to clean the Resource Pool's 'Share Resources' list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry.
You would be best served by rebuilding the resource pool file.  I'm actually surprised you haven't had a fatal corruption of the project files yet.

Link to MS TechNet question with MS response:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/79d286b4-545d-4e38-9abf-70ac31dbc984/testing-ms-project-professional-2013

Comment: Thanks Julie, was checking elsewhere and found the same advice from an MS rep on their forum... How painful!

Comment: Not surprising it is the same advice--that is also me on the TechNet forum.  However, I am not a Microsoft employee.  Just a volunteer.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old and relates to Ms Project 2013 (standard) and I'm on the Pro version, but just in case anyone else (like me) comes here looking for the answer to this question, here's what I found.

REF: http://ntrajkovski.com/2014/07/21/cancelling-project-when-using-resource-pool-in-ms-project-2013/

Note: I found it better to use 'Resource Usage' view in the resource pool so you can see you changes taking effect.

Comment: Hi Damo, welcome to PMSE! Would you mind expanding your answering adding the details, not only the link? The idea is that, if the link breaks down, the content is not lost. Thanks!